# $C^1[0,1]$ is dense in $Lip([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

My question is related to this [post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115726/differentiable-functions-dense-in-lipschitz-functions)

What I don't quite get is why the OP's approach doesn't work. He said that not every Lipschitz function f on $[0,1]$ with Lipschitz constant less than 1 arises by considering $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xF(t)dt$ with $F$ being bounded by 1. I don't understand why not? because by Rademacher theorem, every $f\in Lip([0,1])$ can be written in this form or am I mistaken something?