# How to prove the Extension Theorem of $ {{W}^{1,p}}\left( U \right) $ when $ p= \infty $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am studying partial differential equations from Mr. Evans' book. In Chapter 5, Section 5.4, I learned the extension theorem:

**Theorem** *Assume $ U $ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Select a bounded open set $V$ such that $U\subset \subset V$(which means $U\subset \overline{U}\subset V$ and $\overline{U}$ is compact). Then there exists a bounded linear operator
$$E:{{W}^{1,p}}\left( U \right)\to {{W}^{1,p}}\left( {{\mathbb{R}}^{n}} \right)$$
such that for each $u\in {{W}^{1,p}}\left( U \right)$:*

*(i)$Eu=u\ \text{a}\text{.e}\text{. in}\ U,$*

*(ii)$Eu$ has support within $V$,*

*(iii)${{\left\| Eu \right\|}_{{{W}^{1,p}}\left( {{\mathbb{R}}^{n}} \right)}}\le C{{\left\| u \right\|}_{{{W}^{1,p}}\left( U \right)}}$, the constant $C$ depending only on $p,U,V$.*

The theorem's condition allows $ p= \infty $, but the theorem actually only proves the case $ p < \infty$.

[At the end of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzjuI.png), it says, "The case $ p= \infty $ is left as an exercise", but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I think the original proof works for $1\leq p \leq \infty$ and does not exclude the case when $p=\infty$. Can you provide a screenshot of your copy?

Comment: The proof as given fails at $p=\infty$ because it uses the density of $C^\infty(\overline U)$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$ @Tab1e

Comment: @Tab1e I checked both editions of Evans, the remark about $p=\infty$ was only added in the 2nd edition. Some links about the closure of smooth functions in Lipschitz/Holder spaces: [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115726/differentiable-functions-dense-in-lipschitz-functions), [link2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244377/density-of-smooth-functions-on-hölder-spaces), [link3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29869/density-of-smooth-functions-under-hölder-metric) (since $W^{1,\infty}=\text{Lip}$)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yeah I see it now. I have the first edition.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474656/extension-theorem-sobolev-spaces) may help.